# Live server extension blocked by windows firewall

Tags: json, windows-firewall

My vscode live server extension is not able to access files from my computer because windows firewall blocked it from accesing my files. For example when I try to load images or audio(generally anything from my computer) it gets blocked. Everything else works fine but it can't access files from my computer. In the devtools console I get an error stating : **Not allowed to load local resource**. I tried going to windows firewall rules to try and remove the rule blocking it from doing this but I was not successful, I also tried to change the port number of live-server to see if it would help but it did not.

Here are the json settings for my live server extension if it would help:

```
{
    "files.autoSave": "off",
    "npm.enableRunFromFolder": true,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "workbench.activityBar.visible": true,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "editor.fontSize": 15,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vs-seti",
    "editor.largeFileOptimizations": false,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome",
    "liveServer.settings.ChromeDebuggingAttachment": false,
    "liveServer.settings.port": 0,
    "liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": ""
}
```

If possible please show me how to get the rule blocking the live server extension on windows firewall rule so that I can remove the rule or also show me another way to tackle this problem.